# Robolectric и синглетон Picasso: Singleton instance already exists

Tags: android, robolectric

Имеем android приложение, с собственным Application классом, в onCreate() которого инициализируется Picasso через `Picasso.setSingletonInstance()`. Созданы юнит-тесты для нескольких методов и для их выполнения добавлен robolectric. Тесты падают на инициализации:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton instance already exists.
    at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.setSingletonInstance(Picasso.java:658)
    at <app>.utils.ImageUtils.initPicasso(ImageUtils.java:106)
    at <app>.utils.ImageUtils.onAppInit(ImageUtils.java:72)
    at <app>.Application.onCreate(Application.java:34)
    at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:140)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:433)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:240)
    ... 34 more
```

*Application.onCreate()* вызывается для каждого теста отдельно, но созданные и проинициализированные синглетоны сохраняются, и конкретно Picasso не нравится, когда его инициализируют повторно.

Как грамотно избавиться от исключения? Понятно, что можно завернуть всё в try - catch и проигнорировать исключение, но, может, есть более красивые решения? Возможно ли как-то указать, что для тестов определенного класса *Applicaton.onCreate()* вызывать не нужно?

gradle, robolectric 3.0.